# Can you identify the screws used in my folding chairs

Tags: screws

I have several teak folding deck chairs to restore. Some screws in a sheath(?) are missing. I took a complete sample to a local, national brand tool and hardware store. The store did not stock it and had no advice on where to find it. I left without asking exactly what to call this multi-part screw as I continue my search.

See picture the pictures below

[image: folding-deck-chair-screw]

What am I looking for?

Comment: You may be able to find something similar doing a [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&tbs=simg:CAESzwEJF8uok0rLUfoawwELELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKLwFuwWAEv8R2gWIEr4FtBKhErMSnTO3NrE2tTb0Mssm4Sa0No4-njMaMH3g_1ZaeFeW8mxwo8vGz6llSnegsGlxtDpxBsFDjkRev7GZNjfloLW6EAEoqYg0oICADDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIE77nrRAwLEJ3twQkaPAoKCghoYXJkd2FyZQoHCgVtZXRhbAoGCgRpcm9uChQKEmhhcmR3YXJlIGFjY2Vzc29yeQoHCgVzdGVlbAw&q=hardware&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxt4fSpaXNAhVO32MKHYfkARcQsw4IKw&biw=1116&bih=945) which can be useful when you don't know the name of something (but have a picture on one).

Answer (score 8):

It's called either a 'Sex Bolt' or a 'Binding Post Bolt'.

Here's a page with some - https://www.grainger.com/category/ecatalog/N-1z0dryp

Comment: Also at [mscdirect](http://www.mscdirect.com/browse/tnpla/86906617?src=pla&cid=PLA-Google-PLA+-+Test&CS_003=7867724&CS_010=86906617&mkwid=[*GCLIP*]&prcid=[*GCLSRC]).

Comment: @Pete - Excellent pointer you gave. How do I shop for the size I need? For example, is it measured from end-to-end (screw top to screw top) in inches, or by a size number, or ... ???

Comment: They're sized in the same way as normal bolts - i.e, length and width, except that the length can be the bolt or the barrel. Length does not include the height of the head, only the shaft. You want ones with long barrels, and the length of the bolt is pretty irrelevant as long as it goes in. For Deck Chairs, I'd recommend stainless steel if you can get it.